# Incorrect syntax near **?**

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Incorrect syntax near '?'. what i am doing wrong?
 i think my vs2012 not supporting oledb connection string and sql coding if i write above code with sqlcommand its all work fine strange error occur which point out insert into statment or ? while with `OleDB` i try to change my db name my server name but nothing happen only point out connection close statment? –

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class insert

Private Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btn.Click

    Dim strConn As String = "Server=localdb\Projects;Database=test;Uid=sa;Pwd=12345;"
          'Dim conn As OleDbConnection

    Try
        Dim sname As String = txt1.Text
        Dim sfname As String = txt2.Text
        Dim scnic As String = txt3.Text
        Dim slimit As String = txt4.Text
        Dim semail As String = txt5.Text
        Dim stel As String = txt6.Text
        Dim stel1 As String = txt7.Text
        Dim qu As String = txt8.Text
        'Dim que As Date = Date.Parse(txt9.Text)
        Dim que As String = txt9.Text
        Dim query As String = String.Empty

        query &= "INSERT INTO tencmp (qnumber, topic, Umcq , Usq , Ulq , Emcq , Esq , Elq, pdate)"
        query &= "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```

is here some thing wrong

```
        Using conn As New sqlConnection(strConn)
            Using comm As New sqlCommand()
                With comm
                    .Connection = conn
                    '.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = query
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@qnumber", sname)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@topic", sfname)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@colPhone", scnic)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@colBranch", slimit)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@colCourse", semail)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@coldblFee", stel)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@dobv", stel1)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@coldblFee1", qu)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@dobv1", que)

                    conn.Open()'error occur here on this id
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End With
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As SqlException
        txt10.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: SQL Server Client use the @ with name for parameters placeholders on your query text

Comment: Are you sure you are using `OleDBConnection` ? because you imported `System.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: yes mahadev this time im using sqlclient befor i try oledb?
http://stackoverflow.com/users/1662394/mahadev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works with SQL classes defined in the Sql Client (against a LOCALDB Sql Server database). This library uses the `@` prefix with a name for parameters placeholders on your query text.

```
query &= "INSERT INTO tencmp (qnumber, topic, Umcq , Usq , Ulq , Emcq , Esq , Elq, pdate)"
query &= "VALUES (@qnumber, @topic, @colPhone, " 
query &=  "@colBranch, @colCourse, @coldblFee, "
query &=  "@dobv, @coldblFee1, @dobv1)"
```

However, given the very undescriptive names of your columns, I am not sure if this list of parameters placeholders match exactly your names.

Comment: Sory for confusion steve error occurred Must declare the scalar variable "@colPhone@colBranch".?
http://stackoverflow.com/users/1197518/steve

Comment: my fault, missing the comma to separate the placeholders